# Reassign user story during sprint?

Tags: scrum, user-stories

If a story is in progress and then swim lanes are code review and QA-ready, how should the assignment of stories work? Should a story remain assigned to the developer? And should the code review and QA tasks be created as sub-tasks in it? Or should the story be re-assigned when it is moved to code review by the developer, and when code review is done, it is moved to QA lane by the reviewer and re-assigned to QA by the reviewer. It seems anti-pattern to re-assign tickets from in-progress to future states. It looks okay to re-assign tickets before it was brought in the sprint but not after.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming (in a sense of SO rules). I think your question is more suitable for https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Scrum does not have anything to say about how the work is done nor how a board is managed. However, many team's look at Kanban's "pull" approaches to answer this. In that case, work is never assigned or given, it is only claimed/taken on. Therefor, work would be moved to "Code Review" by the reviewer when they began the work. Similarly, the work would be moved to QA by the tester when they started. "Ready" columns are a bit of a misnomer as they are not states. Rather, they are statuses of the previous state. If your order is Code Review - QA Ready - QA, then in fact, QA ready is a possible designation on work in Code Review. This may seem minor, but it is very important to prevent pile-ups in your process where work stalls without owners.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so if we look at the original question, even if work is pulled from "QA Ready" to "QA", one is user story status gets changed but should it be re-assigned as well? means changing the original owner?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer, but one way of doing it is to think of of a User Story as a container of tasks where each task is a small technical deliverable of any kind. With this mindset you can effectivly stop thinking of who the assignee is as each developer will have its small contribution towards the goal.

One of the problems with task re-assignment is that at one point you can loose traceability of who has done what and productivity on per developer basis. So in this sense having each teammember doing its own tasks and delivering towards the completion of a user story can solve this.

Then you can assign the User Story to the product owner, or you can assign it to a developer that kind of holds ownership towards its delivery to test when the tester will take over. But the user story when assigned to a developer does not mean that he owns the User Story, it just means that it is his responsibility to ensure hand over to test nothing more nothing less.

When a tester encounters a bug then you create a bug attached to the User story.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended. It's feasible tho. You have to assess your current work situation. If the user story is something that can make a whole difference, then it would be better to just stop the sprint, reassess your situation and make the necessary changes - then continue. Either way, when you are adding a new user story to the backlog, deadlines can be hardly met.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a little bit different approach. Like we have following columns on Jira Board.

1. To-do
2. In_progress
3. Ready for Review
4. Ready for QA
5. In-Testing
6. Rework/Rejected
7. Done

A developer pick a task from to-do and assign it to him self and keep it in-progress. Once he is done he moved it to Ready for Review and keep it un assign. Someone will pick it and assign it to himself and review it. After reviewing that person will move the case to ready for QA without assigning it to anyone. Whoever is free or plaining to work on case will assign that case to himself and when he starts working on the case, he will move it to in-testing. As a result of testing the case can go in rework/rejected or in Done. If it moved to Rework/Rejected he will assign it to original person who initially worked on it. And that person when rework on it, will move the case to in-progress again.